# How to add static route with preferred source via Netplan in 18.04?

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, netplan

I want to use loopback alias IP for all outcome IP traffic from my Ubuntu server directed to some subnets.

In `/etc/network/interfaces` that can be done by post-up statement with something like:

```
/sbin/ip route add 1.2.3.0/24 via 10.255.255.254 src 10.255.254.1
```

Is there a way to do that with Netplan and Networkd?

Answer (score 0):

For information about configuring source-based policy routing in netplan, see: https://netplan.io/examples#source-routing

Comment: This is not source-based policy routing, it's destination base pbr with src-ip replacing. I want It to simulate some cisco-like logic with loopback address as source IP for outgoing packets.

Answer (score 0):

The 'from' property of routes does the equivalent of `src` in `ip route`. I think your route would be:

```
  routes:
     - to: 1.2.3.4/24
       via: 10.255.255.254
       from: 10.255.254.1
```

Be aware that:

- Because of [LP: #1767849](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1767849), this doesn't work at all until you get netplan 0.40. As of 2018-09-27, this hasn't been released for Bionic yet, only the still in-development Cosmic.
- even with that fix, it doesn't work reliably for IPv6, because of [systemd bug #5882](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/5882). (You can work around this by running 'netplan apply' late in boot.)